# Python Postfix Notation Stack Class

Tags: python, stack, postfix-notation

I am having to write a Stack class that uses postfix notation for calculating problems entered from a text file using Python. I am also suppose to update the list and not allow there to be more than 10 items in it at any one time. Something appears to be wrong with my push or pop method, I believe. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Updated written code:

```
class Stack:
    #initializing the data
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = [None] * 10
        self.__length = 0

    #destroying the existing stack
    def __destroy__(self):
        self.__data = [None] * 10
        self.__length = 0
        return

    #checking to see if the stack is empty
    def is_stack_empty(self):
        return self.__length == 0

    #checking to see if the stack is full
    def is_stack_full(self):
        if self.__length == 10:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    #pushing an item to the stack
    def push(self, item):
        try:
            self.__data.append(item)
            self.__length = self.__length + 1
            return
        except IndexError:
            print("ERROR: Cannot push more than 10 items to the stack.")


    #popping an item from the stack
    def pop(self):
        try:
            return self.__data.pop()
            self.__length = self.__length - 1
            return
        except IndexError: 
            print("ERROR: Cannot pop from an empty list.")


    #checking to see what the last item on the stack is
    def top(self):
        return self.__data[-1]

    #checking the length of the stack
    def __len__(self):
        return self.__length

    #overloading the string operator
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__data)





def main():
    file_name = input("Enter the name of the file containing postfix expressions: ")   
    #expression = input("Enter a mathmatical expression: ")
    #e_list = expression.split()
    #validates file
    found = False

    while not found:
        try:
            in_file = open(file_name)
            found = True
        except Exception as ex:
            print(file_name, " is not found.")
            file_name = input("Please re-enter a valid text file name: ")

    stack = Stack()

    for each in in_file:
        try:
            value = int(each)
        except Exception as ex:
            second = stack.pop()
            first = stack.pop()

            if each == "+":
                try:
                    answer = first + second
                    stack.push(answer)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print("ERROR: "+ expression + " is an invalid postfix expression.")
            elif each == "-":
                try:
                    answer = first - second
                    stack.push(answer)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print("ERROR: "+ expression + " is an invalid postfix expression.")  
            elif each == "*":
                try:
                    answer = first * second
                    stack.push(answer)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print("ERROR: "+ expression + " is an invalid postfix expression.")
            elif each == "/":
                try:
                    answer = first / second
                    stack.push(answer)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print("ERROR: "+ expression + " is an invalid postfix expression.")
        else:
            stack.push(value)
    print("Answer: ", stack.pop())


    return


main()
```

File content:

```
5 10 * 6 +
20 5 /
3 8 6 + *
3 4 + 9 - 12 +
9 3 2 1 + + /
3 + 5
* 3 4 5 + *
4 9 1 3 + -
h 3 +
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 + / - * + + + + + * * /
```

Resulting output:

```
Enter the name of the file containing postfix expressions: expressions.txt
Expression:  5 10 * 6 +

Answer:  56

Expression:  20 5 /

Answer:  4.0

Expression:  3 8 6 + *

Answer:  42

Expression:  3 4 + 9 - 12 +

Answer:  10

Expression:  9 3 2 1 + + /

Answer:  1.5

ERROR: 3 + 5
is an invalid postfix expression.
Expression:  3 + 5

Answer:  5

ERROR: * 3 4 5 + *
is an invalid postfix expression.
Expression:  * 3 4 5 + *

Answer:  27

Expression:  4 9 1 3 + -

Answer:  5

ERROR: h 3 +
is an invalid postfix expression.
Expression:  h 3 +

Answer:  None

Expression:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 + / - * + + + + + * * /
Answer:  0.0
```

Expected output:

```
Enter the name of the file containing postfix expressions: expressions.txt
Expression:  5 10 * 6 +

Answer:  56

Expression:  20 5 /

Answer:  4.0

Expression:  3 8 6 + *

Answer:  42

Expression:  3 4 + 9 - 12 +

Answer:  10

Expression:  9 3 2 1 + + /

Answer:  1.5

ERROR: 3 + 5 is an invalid postfix expression

ERROR: * 3 4 5 + * is an invalid postfix expression

ERROR: 4 9 1 3 + - is an invalid postfix expression

ERROR: h 3 + is an invalid postfix expression

ERROR: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 + / - * + + + + + * * / is an invalid postfix expression
```

Comment: Look at the value of `each` before you try to pop anything off the stack, to see *why* `int(each)` fails. As a general rule, don't catch anything as broad as `Exception` unless you at least log the actual exception you catch, or plan to re-raise.

Comment: While we're at it, you're overcomplicating many of your methods. Instead of `if something: return True else: return False`, just `return something`. And if you just want to check if a list is non-empty, you can just use the list itself (a non-empty sequence is truthy; an empty one is falsey), rather than checking its length.

Comment: One last thing: If `pop` prints an error but does nothing for an empty stack, `push` should probably print an error but do nothing for a full stack, instead of silently growing the stack beyond its maximum size. (If you decide to go with the fixed-size list and separate length design, pushing to a full stack will raise an exception that you aren't checking for; if you go with the growing list, it will leave the stack in an invalid state that violates its invariants. Neither one is what you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You replaced `e_list` with `in_file`, but they are not the same thing: the former was a list of symbols like `['5', '10', '*', '6', '+']`, while the later is an iterator over a file, so that each is now `5 10 * 6 +`, not a single element from the string.

```
for expression in in_file:
    e_list = expression.split()
    for each in e_list:
        try:
            value = int(each)
        except ValueError as ex:
            second = stack.pop()
            first = stack.pop()

            # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input format is a stream of lines, each of which is a stream of whitespace-separated tokens making up an expression, like this:

```
5 10 * 6 +
20 5 /
```

But your code tries to treat each line as a single token:

```
for each in in_file:
    try:
        value = int(each)
```

You need a nested loop here, with the inner loop splitting on whitespace, to handle each token of each line as intended:

```
for line in in_file:
    for token in line.split():
```

---

It's not clear whether you're supposed to reset the stack for each new line or not. If you are, you either need to create a new `Stack` for each line:

```
for line in in_file:
    stack = Stack()
    for token in line.split():
```

… or `destroy` the stack at the end of each line so you can reuse it:

```
stack = Stack()
for line in in_file:
    for token in line.split():
        # etc.
    stack.__destroy__()
```

---

Also, your `Stack` class has a serious problem you need to fix. Some of your methods (`__init__`, `is_stack_full`, ) use `__data` as a fixed-sized list of 10 elements and a separate `__length` that tells you how many of those elements are valid values, while others (`__destroy__`, `is_stack_empty`, `top`, `__len__`, `__str__`) use `__data` as a list of 0-10 elements that are all valid, and others (`push`, `pop`) mix up the two in the same method. You have to pick one design or the other, and fix the methods using the wrong one.

---

As a more minor point: Your `__destroy__` method is a public method called by your main code, not the implementation of a Python protocol like `__init__`, so it should be named `destroy`. Your `__data` attribute is a regular "by-convention" private value, not a value that you need to hide from superclasses and/or subclasses to avoid accidental collision, so it should be `_data`.

---

There may, of course, be other bugs in your code, but this should be enough to get you over the current hurdle (and the next one you hadn't anticipated).

Comment: I am trying to update the self.__length each time an item is popped or pushed to the stack so there is only a max of 10 items in the stack, but it does not appear to be updating. Is there a problem with the way the above code goes about it, excluding methods other than push/pop?

Comment: @ConnorChapin Yes, all the methods that use `len(self.__data)` are ignoring `self.__length`, so they need to be fixed. Also, some of them shrink and expand `self.__data` instead of just indexing the fixed-size list using `self.__length`, which also needs to be fixed. For example, `__destroy__` should be doing the same thing as `__init__`.